# 'phonegap/cordova' não é reconhecido como comando interno

Tags: html, css, apache-cordova, cmd, prompt

'phonegap/cordova' não é reconhecido como comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Estava com este erro e estava quebrando a cabeça, vou compartilhar para quem está tendo problemas com o comando phonegap no prompt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Configurando as variáveis de desenvolvimento

Se você está com este erro, sete as variáveis de desenvolvimento.

- Botão direito do mouse em `computador -> propriedades -> configurações avançadas... -> variáveis de ambiente`.
- Na variável do sistema chamada: `path` edite-a. e coloque o caminho onde o seu npm está instalado, geralmente é neste local:
  `C:\Users\{USUARIO}\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm` **mas calma aí**
  **Obs:** cuidado para não remover os diretórios antigos, para 'concatenar' com os outros diretórios basta inserir um `;`(ponto e virgula) depois da última, e assim insira o local do seu npm.

## Editando o registro do windows

- Vá em `iniciar -> regedit -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> windows script(pode estar outro nome, mas parecido)->settings`
- Se tiver algo no lado direito como: Enabled, clique e edite o valor para `1`, caso nao, crie um com o `botao direito -> novo -> DWORD`, nome Enabled e valor 1. Feche todos os prompts abertos e abra de novo.

Lembre-se sempre de iniciar o prompt como administrador.

- Aquele diretório que falei no inicio: `C:\Users\{USUARIO}\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm`, ele por padrão vem assim: `C:\Users\{USUARIO}\AppData\Roaming\npm;npm\npm`, esse ponto e vírgula `npm;npm`, na hora de setar as varivaeis de ambiente pode atrapalhar, porque ele serve para 'concatenar' os valores, dentro daquela variável. Substitua o `npm;npm` por `npm`, faça a alteração nas variáveis de ambiente e pronto.

Feito isso, se o seu prompt estiver aberto feche-o e abra novamente para que as alterações sejam feitas. Agora para verificar se o erro persiste é só digitar `npm -v`.